# file upload in php name of the author of the file

Tags: php, file, upload

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

This file upload works for me perfectly. But I want something more:
If someone uploads a file, I see only the file that he uploaded.
I dont see the name of the author of that document.

Is possible to make something like that?

Comment: What do you mean by `name of the author of that document` ?

Comment: to see the name of who uploaded the file. actually it shows only the file itself

Answer (score 0):

I had code for file upload you can compare it with your code to see where the problem .

About the extension you need to make sure you upload to your database and upload folder the correct extension .

**NOTE:** before you use the code make sure you have folder call it (uploads) and inside this folder make another folder call it (avatar) so you can upload it in your folder in server when you use the code i post it .

```
      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="avatar">
      </form>
if(isset($_FILES['avatar'])){
       //If you want to see the array for file do this
       //print_r($_FILES['avatar']);

        // avatar array
        $avatarName = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
        $avatarSize = $_FILES['avatar']['size'];
        $avatarTmp = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];
        $avatarType = $_FILES['avatar']['type'];

        // list of allowed file typed to upload
        $avatarAllowedExtension = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif');

        // get avatar extension
        $tmp = explode('.', $avatarName);
        $avatarExtension = strtolower(end($tmp));

        if (!empty($avatarName) && !in_array($avatarExtension, $avatarAllowedExtension)) {
            echo 'This extension is not allowed';
        }

        if (empty($avatarName)) {
            echo 'Avatar is required';
        }

        if ($avatarSize > 4194304) {
            echo 'Avatar cant be larger than 4mb';
        }
       //using rand(min,max) to insert in database different name
       $avatar = rand(0, 100000000000) . '_' . $avatarName;
//to keep file insert folder if you want to show it or if you want to download it in your website
       move_uploaded_file($avatarTmp, 'uploads\avatar\\' . $avatar);
//If you want to upload file use $avatar because you need different name in your database but when you show it to user you can show the original name for user file
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your system does not save the name, you can not display it. The graphics file there are not include authors' name.